# invalid syntax print in Python 3.3.0

Tags: python, printing, syntax-error

When I try this at the REPL in Python 3.3:

```
>>> def fact(n):
...     res = 1
...     while n > 1: 
...     res *= n
...     n -= 1
...     return res
...
>>> print fact(23)
```

I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In python 3.x [print](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print) is a function. Try `print(fact(23))` instead.